# SQL ternary relationship design

Tags: sql, database-design

I haven't done any database conception for a long time and I'm quite rusted. I would like your opinion on the designs I've made because I feel like something's wrong or could be heavily improved

Now here are the rules I want:

- A user can have zero or many characters
- A character belongs to a server
- A character can be in a guild **or not** (tricky part)
- A guild belongs to a server (therefore the character and guild must be in the same server)
- A guild has a guildmaster (which is a character)

Here is the first thing I came up with:

[image: first thing]

And here is the second

[image: second one]

Can I have your opinion/suggestions on those? Thanks in advance!

Comment: On the second one, character shouldn't have idServer; a character belongs to a guild and the guild belongs to a server (basically the character's idServer should be obtained by going to its guild). Other than that, it seems reasonable.

Comment: Problem is a character doesn't necessarily belongs to a guild, so if the character doesn't have a guild he doesn't belong to any server

Comment: cool; it makes sense then :)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong; what makes you uneasy ?

Comment: Does it make sense to have an idGuild in the character? Is it ok to have two relations between character and guild? Should I make a "guildMember" table as in the first one? When I personnaly look at this it feels not really solid

Comment: I like the second best... with the NULLable idGuild directly on the character. Since the guildmaster is bound to exist (I desume that from the relation you have drawn)... I would just be in doubt as to the presence of idServer on the guild table. It is certainly more efficient in queries than going through the guildmaster relation onto the character table to find the idServer... OTOH it is redundant and adds to the integrity constraints you must enforce (it denormalizes, not much, but a bit).

Comment: You do have two relationships between guild and character, so it's ok; your problem will be enforcing that the guildmaster is a character in the guild. You could instead have a flag on character specifying whether it is a guild master, but then enforcing the constraint that only one character is the master is harder ... 6 of one, half-a-dozen of the other, IMHO

Comment: @okaram: Yes.  Sometimes, your database cannot enforce all constraints.  Sometimes, your application code has to enforce certain constraints.